# find average from list with sessions

Tags: java, list, session, average

Hello guys I am stucked and I need your help to this :
I have a .txt file that is something like this:

[image: Click to see how .txt]

Each session begins with Begin and ends with END 
So I have a lot of sessions ....
Now I want for ALL sessions to calculate an average value for example 
if value1=1.0    ---> avg(value2) = (10 + 4) /2 = 7
So far i have made 2 lists that keeps values of value1 and value2.
Now I can calculate for 1 session easily of course but I cant keep the average value when i go to next session .
I put the average value at a new list but it reset for every session. I need to keep the average values for each session.So far this works :

```
if (value1 ==1.0 )
{

      double sum=0;
      double avg=0;       

       sum +=value2;
       avg = sum / count;

       AverageList[ListCount].add(avg);

       System.out.println("Average:" + AverageList[ListCount]);

       }
```

Comment: what is `AverageList[ListCount].add()` ? Doesn't look like java

Comment: It is a LinkedList -> AverageList[ListCount]=new LinkedList<Double>();

Comment: you can't access a linked list via brackets `[`, `]`

Comment: LinkedList[ListCount] means that i create a number of linked lists like this LinkedList[0] -> [some values] , LinkedList[1] -> [some other values] , Listcount is a counter that I have in order to grab all values from all sessions